# When does a stream become a river?

Tags: rivers

Does a stream require a certain width or volume before it can be classified as a river, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no official distinction between a river and a creek, both of which are categories of streams. As an example, consider [Pine Creek in Pennsylvania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_Creek_(Pennsylvania)) and [Po River in Spotsylvania County, Virginia](https://us.geoview.info/po_river,37946879w). Pine Creek is 87.2 miles long and has a flow rate that ranges between [40 to 30000 cubic feet per second](https://waterdata.usgs.gov/monitoring-location/01549700/#parameterCode=00060&period=P3650D). Po River on the other hand is 1.9 miles long and has a row rate that ranges between [less than 2 to 4000 cubic feet per second](https://waterdata.usgs.gov/monitoring-location/01673800/#parameterCode=00060&period=P3650D). The longer and larger one is called a creek while the shorter and smaller one is called a river.